# Applicative with zero

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I was just working on application and encountered case where I'd like to abstract over appendable collections. I came up with the following type class.

```
trait AppendableCollection[F[_]] {
  def empty[A]: F[A]
  def append[A](fa: F[A])(a: A): F[A]
}

object AppendableCollection {
  implicit val reversedListCollection = new Collection[List] {
    def empty[A] = Nil
    def append[A](fa: List[A])(a: A) = a :: fa
  }
}
```

It kinda looks like Applicative with zero but and I bet there is something like this available in cats or its ecosystem?

Comment: None of the representations of applicative (`apply`, `map2`, `map + product`) looks anything like what you showed here. Your question about a typeclass with such functions still makes sense, but I would remove the "applicative" part from it. If anything, it's much more similar to a monoid, as pointed out by @Dmytro Mitin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided there is `pure(a: A): F[A]`, looks similar to `MonoidK`

```
trait MonoidK[F[_]] {
  def empty[A]: F[A]
  def combineK[A](x: F[A], y: F[A]): F[A]
}
```

https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/MonoidK.scala#L25